# How do you download a web page in Arch Linux

Tags: linux

Totally new to Linux, have an Arch Linux machine up.  What is the command I can execute on the console to download a web page in the console?
Thanks

Comment: Very nice. A non-programming question on SO not closed and/or migrated.

Comment: In future flag question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is wget installed?

```
wget http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320913/how-do-you-download-a-web-page-in-arch-linux
```

Answer (score 3):

If You want download whole page to the disc, good practice is use wget with options -k -r -p:

```
wget -k -r -p http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320913/how-do-you-download-a-web-page-in-arch-linux
```

This command is downloading recursively all the files that are necessary to properly display a given html page and convert the links to make them suitable for local viewing.

Answer (score 1):

try wget see http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

```
wget
```

Answer (score 1):

[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is another good option. Have fun with Linux!